# Navigation issue in swift3 with .xib files without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, xib

I used .xib files instead of using storyboard in my swift project. While navigating the particular view controllers getting delay. I tried the navigation code inside the **DispatchQueue.main.async{}** also but the performance getting delay to navigate the view controllers.

Comment: Even if you have used the storyboard it might have had the same problem. Post your navigation code here.

Comment: Its never good idea to do user interface work on the background thread

Comment: let managePayerObj = ManagePayer(nibName: (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? "ManagePayer" : "ManagePayer_iPhone"), bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(managePayerObj, animated: true)
My navigation code..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue, I used a font in .xib which is not added in .plist. I changed that font now the view controller navigating without delay.